# GenericForeignKey filtering issue with multiple rows

Tags: orm, django-models

I have a table that includes the below:

```
content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, null=True, default=None)
object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, default=None)
content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

I want to be able to filter in cases where the `content_type` is `Null` OR if the `content_type` is not `Null`, I want it to check the `active` field in the particular object and make sure it's 'Y'. How can I perform that comparison?

I checked many sites including the below:

http://ui.co.id/blog/generic-field-filtering-in-django

**EDIT**

My only solution to this is to have a `for loop` after the filter statements where I loop through and I eliminate any object that doesn't have the proper `active` field. This is inefficient...is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case probably you may do something like this:

## Case1:

```
result = []
result += Model.objects.filter(content_type__isnull=True)
```

## Case2:

```
active_object_ids = ObjectClass.objects.filter(active='Y').values_list('id', flat=True)
result += Model.objects.filter(object_id__in = active_object_ids)
```

Only drawback is in the case 2 you may have to collect all the ids for all the objects linked by the GFK. Also, since, whenever you save the content_object, content_type is saved with it so, you need not test for content_type in the second case.

Comment: actually, the `content_object` has the `active` field, I should have been a bit more clear I guess